# How can I specify errorStyle and warnStyle for JSF messages globally?

Tags: java, jsf, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, java-ee-7

I'm writing tiny web-application using JSF2.2 and Twitter Bootstrap for client side.

I customized the look of list elements dumped by `<h:messages>` tag, but now I have to specify its `errorStyle` and `warnStyle` every time use `<h:messages>` something like this:

```
<h:messages class="messages" errorClass="has-error" warnClass="has-warning"/>
```

Is there a way to get rid of such boilerplate markup? Can I *set these attributes globally* somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the primefaces css styles globally for your project specific way once.

For example, I have overridden as below once in my CSS.
You can view the primefaces css using plugins like FireBug.

```
            .ui-messages-info,.ui-messages-warn,.ui-messages-error,.ui-messages-fatal
                {
                width: 795px;
                min-height: 20px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-top: none;
                border-right: none;
                border-bottom: none;
                border-left-width: 5px;
            }

            .ui-messages-warn,.ui-message-warn {
                border-left-color: rgb(224, 203, 82);
                color: brown;
            }

            .ui-messages-error,.ui-message-error {
                border-left-color: rgb(224, 82, 82);
            }

            .ui-messages-info,.ui-message-info {
                border-left-color: rgb(82, 224, 82);
                background: rgb(233, 251, 233);
                color: green;
            }

            .ui-messages-warn-icon {
                background: url('../images/warning_24x24.png');
            }

            .ui-messages-error-icon {
                background: url('../images/error_24x24.png');
            }

            .ui-messages-info-icon {
                background: url('../images/success_24x24.png');
            }

            .ui-messages-warn-summary {
                font-weight: normal;
            }
```

And in your pages you can just have as below, it would dynamically behave according to error, warn, info, etc,

```
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
```

Comment: OP hasnt mentioned using primefaces anywhere